# Problem with try catch SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, html, spring

I'm creating a website, and I want to handle white label error. When a white label occurs, then I'd like the system to be sent to a new page.

I'm having trouble with the following method

```
@PostMapping("/createRental")
public String createRental(@ModelAttribute Rental rental) throws Exception{
    try {
        rentalService.createRental(rental);
        return "home/rental/succesRental";
    } catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
        return "home/rental/noRental";
    }
}
```

As of right now, my im getting this error: SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
"home/rental/succesRental"; works, but "home/rental/noRental"; doesn't, and that's the page I'd like to be sent to, instead of a white label error. Any fixes?

Comment: You're catching `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` but write you get a `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. If that's really the case, you need to catch the more generic `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: I've also tried SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException in the catch but that doesn't work either. the error says: Exception 'java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block

Comment: What does `createRental()` throw?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, since im still new to coding.
What I want to achieve is for the sytem to be able to go to "home/rental/succesRental"; HTML file which works, and if a white label occurs, then I'ld like the webpage to show this html file "home/rental/noRental";

Comment: is there a mapping defined for "home/rental/noRental" ? Exactly what error you are facing?

Comment: Well, if you're new to programming you might want to get a good grasp of the basics first which would include how to use exceptions. Assuming your mapping of the return values works you seem to have a problem with returning `"home/rental/noRental"` because your code doesn't enter the catch clause, right? In that case you'd need to check what checked exceptions `createRental()` declares to be thrown or what runtime/unchecked exceptions it could throw and which you'd want to catch.

Comment: I'm also not sure you are aware of what "white label" means: this basically happens when Spring catches an exception without being able to send the user to a specific error page (thus the error label is blank or "white"). The user is then sent to a _generic_ error page. In your case "no rental" would be a specific error page so a white label would not be what you want.